# Add Blog to WP homepage Manually

Tags: posts, loop

I'm using the »[Free e-commerce Theme Balita](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/19/free-e-commerce-wordpress-theme-balita/)«, as posted on Smashing Magazine.

It's great, but doesn't have the standard WP blog with corresponding number of post per homepage as settings; as default Twenty Eleven.

> **Q:** How do I manually add the blog to appear at homepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the theme is widgetized, and it actually has listed as a feature ["Blog integration" - see here](http://tokokoo.com/demo/wpec38/balita/blog/). Are you sure in the theme settings there are not options related to showing blog posts in one of the widget areas?

The other place to look is "Appearance » Widgets". There may be a built-in Widget to display recent posts.

The third option is using another widget to display blog content. I have been happy with [the "flexible recent posts" plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flexible-recent-posts/) myself, but there are a lot if you search.

None of these options should even require editing code, they can all be done from the UI.

Comment: Thanks Greg - Cool solutions; and just gave that plugin a try. Though it's coming off and displaying really small and as an excerpt. I was hoping to recreate the default 'twenty eleven' blog style under my custom theme

Comment: +1 for the answer @Cam There's no "default" blog in WordPress. You can "hack" code or use plugins. At the end it will be in your hands (or those of a developer that you hire), to integrate the changes that you need (longer excerpt, etc.). You can also [search here on WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=excerpt) or go through the [list of tags](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags) _OR_ take a look at [tag:the-excerpt] and [tag:excerpt].

Comment: I was referencing Twenty Eleven; Yeah OK I'll look for the PHP, thanks.

Comment: Got it -- just did some manual digging. Cheers dudes.